# Can't display postgresql query as Combobox in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a query that executes perfectly in Postgresql:

```
SELECT 
      matchid
    , f1.firstname
    , f1.lastname
    , f2.firstname
    , f2.lastname
FROM matches AS m
    INNER JOIN fighters AS f1
        ON f1.fighterid = m.fighteroneid
    INNER JOIN fighters AS f2
        ON f2.fighterid = m.fightertwoid
```

It displays one row with the fighters, but when I attempt to display the results in a combo box it displays as "System.Data.DataRow" as opposed to the data.

Code in VB.NET:

```
mySelectQuery = "SELECT f1.firstname, f1.lastname, f2.firstname, f2.lastname FROM matches AS m INNER JOIN fighters AS f1 ON f1.fighterid = m.fighteroneid INNER JOIN fighters AS f2 ON f2.fighterid = m.fightertwoid"

pgAdapter = New PgSqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, pgConnection)
    pgAdapter.Fill(dtMatches)

    With cboMatches
        .DisplayMember = "fighters"
        .ValueMember = "matchid"
        .DataSource = dtMatches
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
```

I have attempted to use fighters, m, f1, f2 as display member and it always returns the same output.

If I move the .DataSource above .DisplayMember I recieve the error: Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember.

Thank you in advance,

Spence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValueMember and DisplayMember should refer to column names of your datasource.
You don't have anything with the names assigned.
You could try to assign one name to the DisplayMember, but your query doesn't produce any MatchID.

I am not an expert in PostegreSQL, but, you could try the following to [aggregate the names](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)

```
mySelectQuery = "SELECT m.MatchID, string_agg(f1.firstname, f1.lastname, ' - ', " + 
                "f2.firstname, f2.lastname, ' ') as Fighters " + 
                "FROM matches AS m INNER JOIN fighters AS f1 ON f1.fighterid = m.fighteroneid" +
                " INNER JOIN fighters AS f2 ON f2.fighterid = m.fightertwoid"
```

and then use

```
With cboMatches  
    .DisplayMember = "Fighters"  
    .ValueMember = "MatchID"  
    .DataSource = dtMatches  
    .SelectedIndex = -1  
End With
```

Comment: I added MatchID to the query, but I guess I just don't understand how to use an alias in the DisplayMember

Comment: My idea (to be tested on a real PostegreSQL db) is: aggregate the names of the fighters separating them with a dash and call the result of the aggregation with the name used as DisplayMember. That's all. To be honest I'm not sure of the correct syntax to be used, but I hope to point you in the right direction

Comment: You did exactly what was needed

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using COALESCE because string_agg does not work with name type without CASTS.

```
SELECT m.MatchID, COALESCE(f1.firstname || ' ' || f1.lastname || ' - ' || f2.firstname || ' ' ||  f2.lastname) as Fighters  
       FROM matches AS m INNER JOIN fighters AS f1 ON f1.fighterid = m.fighteroneid 
       INNER JOIN fighters AS f2 ON f2.fighterid = m.fightertwoid
```

Comment: Giving other credit because he pointed me in the right direction. Thanks to all for the help